# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined and Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to write wiki viewer in the pure javascript and got the 'Uncaught TypeError' This is in the line where the data is stringify. The stringify is not catching the url string. Any help?
    -------------------------------------------------------

```
    Name: <input type="text" id = "myText" value="" placeholder="Search for ..." />
        <button type="submit">Submit Search</button>
        <div id="otpt"></div>



    var url;

        function winit() {
            var endPoint = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?";

            var searchStr = document.getElementById("myText").value;

            var wikiPara = {
                // Main Parameters
                action: 'query',
                format: 'json',
                titles: searchStr,
                prop: 'revisions',
                rvprop: 'content',
                callback: 'wikiCall',   

            }
            var txt = "";

            for (var i in wikiPara) {
                txt += i + "=" + wikiPara[i];
                if (i != "callback")
                    txt += "&amp;";
            }

            var url = endPoint + txt;
        }

        function getScript() {
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
            script.src = url;

            document.body.appendChild(script);
        }

        function getScript() {
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
            script.src = url;

            document.body.appendChild(script);
        }


        function wikiCall(response) {
            document.getElementById("otpt").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(response.query.pages);
        }


        addEventListener("click", function completeW() {
                winit();
                getScript();
                wikiCall();
        }, false);
```

Comment: You didn't pass any parameters to `wikiCall()`

Comment: What you think, which parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function wikiCall(response) {
    document.getElementById("otpt").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(response.query.pages);
}
```

Here you are trying to chain off of the `response` object passed to `wikiCall` --however, the only place I see you actually *call* that function, you don't pass it anything:

```
addEventListener("click", function completeW() {
    winit();
    getScript();
    wikiCall(); /* <== Here is the only place wikiCall is invoked and you pass it no arguments. */
}, false);
```

However, I don't see where you actually make the call, so I suspect that perhaps you have some larger problems with your architecture here.

Comment: He is also accessing a response.query property, when the only instance of a query word in the codebase is inside the wikiPara object that has "query" as a value of the action property.

Comment: Sure, fair point-- but it is possible that he/she is getting a response object from some third party or remote DB-- but you may be correct.  I suspect that there are some larger problems at play here.

Comment: True. The pages property in response.query.pages does seem to be not included in the given code.